# How can I compare the most recent commit with the previous commit?

Tags: git

How can I compare my most recent commit with the previous commit?
I'd like to know the diff between `83a853349d91c855442c` and `35ad2211a1cc7d0dbd49` (without having to specify the actual commit sha)

```
$ git log
commit 83a853349d91c855442c
Author: Jagat<myemail@email.com>
Date:   Thu Aug 22 11:44:27 2019 -0700

    Most recent commit

commit 35ad2211a1cc7d0dbd49
Author: Jagat<myemail@email.com>
Date:   Thu Aug 22 09:35:12 2019 -0700

    fix compilation
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use a bare `git show` for the most recent commit. From the [docs](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-show):

> For commits it shows the log message and textual diff. It also presents
>   the merge commit in a special format as produced by git diff-tree
>   --cc.

Answer (score 0):

```
git diff HEAD~1 HEAD
```

HEAD~1 is the penultimate commit (1 is the index), while HEAD refers to the most recent committed state.

Answer (score 0):

You need two things:

- The latest commit in the current branch is pointed by `HEAD`. In your example, `83a853349d91c855442c`.
- One of the ways to point to the first previous commit is `<rev>^` (if there are multiple parent commits, use `<rev>^<n>` to point to the `n`-th parent). In your example, `HEAD^` points to `35ad2211a1cc7d0dbd49`.

Therefore:

```
git diff HEAD^ HEAD
```